# Dealing with network packet loss in realtime games - TCP and UDP

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, packet-loss

Reading lots on this for my first network game, I understand the core difference of guaranteed delivery versus time-to-deliver for TCP v UDP. I've also read diametrically opposed views whether realtime games should use UDP or TCP! ;)

What no-one has covered well is how to handle the issue of a dropped packet.

TCP : Read an article using TCP for an FPS that recommended only using TCP. How would an authoritative server using TCP client input handle a packet drop and sudden epic spike in lag? Does the game just stop for a moment and then pick up where it left off? Is TCP packet loss so rare that it's not really that much of an issue and an FPS over TCP actually works well?

UDP : Another article suggested only ever using UDP. Clearly one-shot UDP events like "grenade thrown" aren't reliable enough as they won't fire some of the time. Do you have to implement a message-received, resend protocol manually? Or some other solution?

My game is a tick-based authoritative server with 1/10th second updates from the server to clients and local simulation to keep things seeming more responsive, although the question is applicable to a lot more applications.

Answer (score 2):

I did a real-time TV editing system. All real-time communication was via UDP, but none-real-time used TCP as it is simpler. With the UDP we would send a state packet every frame. e.g. `start video in 100 frames, 99,98,…3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3` so even if no message gets through until -3 then the receiver would start on the 4th frame (just skipping the first 3), hoping that no one would notice, and knowing that this was better than lagging from here on in. We even added the countdown from around +¼ second (as no-one will notice), this way hardly any frames where dropped.

So in summary, we sent the same status packet every frame. It contained all real-time data about past, current, and future events.

The trick is keeping this data-set small. So instead of sending play button pressed event (there is an unbound number of these), we send the video-id, frame-number, start-mask and end-mask. (start/stop mask are frame numbers, if start-mask is positive and stop-mask is negative then show video, at frame frame-number).

Now we need to be able to start a video during another or shortly after it stops. So we consider how many consecutive video can be played at the same time. We need a slot for each, but can we reuse them immediately? If we have pressed stop, so do not know the stop mask until then, then reuse the slot will the video stop. Well there will be no slot for this video, so we should stop it. So yes we can reuse the slot immediately, as long as we use unique IDs.

Other tips: Do not send +1 events instead send current total. If two players have to update the some total, then each should have their own total, sum all totals at point of use, but never edit someone else's total.